# Need to return the displayed value not formula when copying a row between sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Im currently using google sheets and  a script to move a portion of row when i select "ok" in a data validation column , the problem is that it copies the formulas of each cell and not the displayed value, and ideas, Im not the best at this so any help is HUGE.

```
/**
* Moves row of data to another spreadsheet based on criteria in column 6 to sheet with same name as the value in column 4.
*/

function onEdit(e) {
    // see Sheet event objects docs
    // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
    var ss = e.source;
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var r = e.range;

    // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
    var actionCol = 6;
    var nameCol = 4;

    // Get the row and column of the active cell.
    var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
    var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

    // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
    // -1 to drop our action/status column
    var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;

    // if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
    if (e.value == "ok" && colIndex == actionCol) {
        // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority  column
        var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
        // if the sheet exists do more stuff
        if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
            // set our target sheet and target range
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
            var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 6);  //6 represents Numer of Columns to Copy
            // get our source range/row
            var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, 6); //6 represents Numer of Columns to Copy
            // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
            sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
            // ..but we can still delete the row after

            // or you might want to keep but note move e.g. r.setValue("moved");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the option to sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange); as described here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)

Please look at the docs before posting, thanks. Good luck.